# whats wrong with my code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, multithreading

What's wrong with my code?? I am initiating the thread in a button click event. I do not get any error but it does not fire the send email sub.

```
Dim thread As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf sendEmail))
        thread.Start()
        thread.IsBackground = True
        thread.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Normal
        Response.Redirect(getRedirectionPath)

 Public Sub sendEmail()

        Response.Redirect("~/Index")

    End Sub
```

Why does not it work?

**Update:** I get the error "THREAD WAS BEING ABORTED"

**Update:** As requested I have uploaded the whole code snippet

```
 Protected Sub btnLocalSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLocalSubmit.Click
        'Dim _User As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(_userName)
        'Dim _UserGUID As Object = _User.ProviderUserKey


        Dim _con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CitizenJDBConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Dim _sqlComm As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO LocalReport VALUES (@UserID,@ReportTitle,@Report,@State,@City,@Locality,'0','0',@Tags,@TimeStamp)", _con)
        Try

            _sqlComm.Parameters.Add("UserID", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
            _sqlComm.Parameters("UserID").Value = _userName

            _sqlComm.Parameters.Add("ReportTitle", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
            _sqlComm.Parameters("ReportTitle").Value = txtLocalReportTitle.Text

            _sqlComm.Parameters.Add("Report", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
            _sqlComm.Parameters("Report").Value = ckLocalReport.Text

            _sqlComm.Parameters.Add("State", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
            _sqlComm.Parameters("State").Value = ddlState.SelectedValue

            _sqlComm.Parameters.Add("City", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
            _sqlComm.Parameters("City").Value = ddlCity.SelectedItem.Value

            _sqlComm.Parameters.Add("Locality", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
            _sqlComm.Parameters("Locality").Value = txtLocation.Text

            _sqlComm.Parameters.Add("Tags", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
            _sqlComm.Parameters("Tags").Value = txtLocalTags.Text

            _sqlComm.Parameters.Add("TimeStamp", Data.SqlDbType.DateTime)
            _sqlComm.Parameters("TimeStamp").Value = DateTime.Now


            _con.Open()
            _sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            _con.Close()

            Dim logic = New connections
            logic.emailsToSend(User.Identity.Name, getURL, reportedBy)
            'sendEmail()
            Dim thread As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf sendEmail))
            thread.Start()
            Response.Redirect(getRedirectionPath)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Response.Write(ex.Message)
        Finally
            _con.Close()
            _con.Dispose()
            _sqlComm.Dispose()

        End Try
    End Sub
    Public Sub sendEmail()
        Dim _con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CitizenJDBConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Dim _sqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM EmailSender", _con)
        Dim _table As New System.Data.DataTable


        Try
            _con.Open()
            _sqlDataAdapter.Fill(_table)
            _con.Close()

            For i As Integer = 0 To _table.Rows.Count


                Dim AppPath As String = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath

                Dim sr As New StreamReader(AppPath & "EmailTemplates/NewReport.txt")
                Dim message As New MailMessage()

                message.IsBodyHtml = True

                message.From = New MailAddress("admin@asdf.com")

                message.To.Add(New MailAddress(_table.Rows(i).Item(1)))

                'message.CC.Add(New MailAddress("monodeep12@gmail.com"))

                message.Subject = "New User registration !"

                message.Body = sr.ReadToEnd()

                sr.Close()

                message.Body = message.Body.Replace("<%ReporterName%>", _table.Rows(i).Item(3))

                message.Body = message.Body.Replace("<%ReportURL%>", _table.Rows(i).Item(2))

                Dim client As New SmtpClient()
                client.Host = "smtp.tricedeals.com"
                'smtp.gmail.com
                client.Port = 25
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = True
                client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin@asdf.com", "111111")
                'smtp.EnableSsl = True
                client.Send(message)
                i += 1
            Next


        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you rewrite your code? Is thread.Start() method in any method? It's nice to see all in file

Comment: @igofed i updaed the error i get..

Comment: Why are you doing Response.Redirect twice?

Comment: What are you trying do do? You are spawning a thread that invokes a method that redirects to another page, then you are redirecting to another page on your main thread? I am confused.

Comment: @Coltech i have updated the question with the original code snippet...i was testing the code to see if it works.

Comment: @Rich i have updated the question with the original code snippet...i was testing the code to see if it works.

Comment: @igofed i have updated the question with the original code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Response.End method ends the page execution and shifts the execution to the Application_EndRequest event in the application's event pipeline. The line of code that follows Response.End is not executed.

This problem occurs in the Response.Redirect and Server.Transfer methods because both methods call Response.End internally.

To work around this problem, use one of the following methods:

For Response.End, call the HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest method instead of Response.End to bypass the code execution to the Application_EndRequest event.

For Response.Redirect, use an overload, Response.Redirect(String url, bool endResponse) that passes false for the endResponse parameter to suppress the internal call to Response.End. For example:
  Response.Redirect ("nextpage.aspx", false);

If you use this workaround, the code that follows Response.Redirect is executed.
For Server.Transfer, use the Server.Execute method instead.

Read More [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629)